# Разница post-запросов

Tags: javascript, post, curl

Я озадачен вопросом. В документации написано, что можно применять запрос *curl*:

```
curl -s -X POST -H ... \
-H ... \
--data "{
  ....
}" "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2"
```

Но я бы хотел использовать javascript. Примерно так:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2',
type: 'post',
data: {
    ....
},
headers: {
   ....,
    ....
},
dataType: 'json'
});
```

Подскажите, есть ли разница. И не гоните, пожалуйста, палками. Только начинаю разбираться с запросами

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите, есть ли разница.

Вызов происходит из глубин командной строки, может быть обработан системными командами или файлами, которые буду на стороне сервера, могут так же выводиться в браузер (необязательно).

```
curl -X POST -H Content-Type: application/json \
-H ... \
--data {
  "someData":"that is formatted as JSON"
}' https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2
```

---

Вызов происходит из "глубин" браузера. Ответ обрабатывается браузерными средствами, например JS, выводиться непосредственно в браузер (обычно на страницу, которая этот вызов инициировала).

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2',
type: 'post',
data: {
    someData: "that is formatted as JSON"
},
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) { console.log(data); }
});
```

---

Есть еще проверки (например: [CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)), которые проводят сегодняшние браузеры, так что возможно некоторые запросы будут проходить через `curl`, но не пройдут через браузерные вызовы.